# Creating Windows self-extracting executables that can auto-run a script

Tags: debian, windows, archive

Does a tool exist (preferably packaged in Debian) to create Windows self-extracting executables that can auto-run a script in the archive once the extracting is done?

I've been toying with [NSIS](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/nsis) but I am not sure it can do what I'm asking and is rather heavyweight for this purpose.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818482/creating-a-self-extracting-zip-archive-on-a-linux-box